# InstaSearch (eclipse plugin) functionality in intelliJ v11.x?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

One thing I miss about moving from eclipse to intelliJ is the [InstaSearch](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) plugin that would let you to search the source code codes of your entire project very quickly, really simple and effective.

Is there such a functionality in intelliJ either baked in or added via a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ supports search and replace in your entire project.

> **To find a text in all files within the specified path**
>   1. On the main menu, choose **Edit | Find | Find in Path**, or press **Ctrl+Shift+F**.
>   2. In the [Find In Path Dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/find-and-replace-in-path.html), specify the following options:
>
> - Text to find (you can select one from the recent history drop-down list).
> - Search scope (project, module or directory).
> - Search options (case sensitivity, whole words, and regular expressions).

See instructions [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html).